# Bootstrap 4 navbar is extremely thin on medium or smaller devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 with rails 5, and am trying to build a collapsing navbar: the collapse and functionality work just fine, but for some reason the size of the collapsed navbar is really small: [image]

When the example on the website gives: 
[image]

Beyond just the navbar, the text size on mine is also much smaller. I don't have any special css in terms of sizing attached to the navbar, so I'm confused why it's significantly smaller than the default size.

_navigationbar.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <!-- Brand -->
   <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>-->

    <!-- Links -->
    <div id="myNavbar">
        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav" id="nav-colors">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>League Builders</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/navigationbar' %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some code? And do you have the viewport meta tag that causes your content to scale to mobile devices, assuming your screenshot is of your site on a phone or mobile device? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't include my code. One second

Comment: Updated my question with code - I haven't heard of that, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like you're on a mobile device and everything (not just the bootstrap nav) is really small. Typically this is from a missing meta viewport tag, which causes your content to scale up on smaller devices. Try adding this to the `<head>` of your site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help

Comment: @NathanLauer my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Coker, this problem was really easily fixed: I simply added the line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the head section of application.html.erb, and it all resolved itself.

Comment: I'll actually add an answer if you want to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Go ahead, I'll accept it. I don't have enough reputation yet for my vote to be seen, but I can still accept it